# Enable Button when there are Items selected in both ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="81,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" SelectionMode="Single"/>
<ListBox x:Name="listbox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="482,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>

<Button x:Name="uButton" Content="Upload stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="840,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" Foreground="#FF0068FF" Click="ButtonClick">
    ...
</Button>
```

I want the button `uButton` to be disabled by using IsEnable = false, until the user selected one Item from `listbox1` and one or more Items from `listbox2`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use `MultiBinding`. Bind to both of the ListView's `SelectedItem` properties and write a simple converter class deriving from `IMultiValueConverter` which does check if all items in the array parameter `paramter` are non-null. Return either false or true then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"` into your listbox1 and listbox2 properties in your xaml code.

add `IsEnabled="False"` into your buttons properties

then in your code

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listbox1.SelectedItem != null && listbox2.SelectedItems != null)
            ubutton.IsEnabled = true;
        else
            ubutton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can be done with Bindings, thus this is not the nicest way. Would work nonetheless, tho'.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. everything seems to work, but only if I changed `listbox2.SelectedItems != null` to `listbox2.SelectedItems.Count > 0`

Comment: Im glad i could help... yeah sorry did not test it XD

Answer (score 2):

Providing you use the MVVM pattern (which you should with WPF), you should implement an ICommand and bind it to the Command Property of your button. In the CanExecute method of your button you can check the Count of the selected Items of your ListBoxes. It automatically enables/disables your button when the criteria are met. This could look something like this:

```
public class SomeCommand: ICommand
{
    #region Fields
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors
    public SomeCommand( MainWindow mw )
    {
        this.mainWindow = mw;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICommand
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute( object parameter )
    {
        return ( this.mainWindow.listbox1.SelectedItems.Count != 0 
                && this.mainWindow.listbox2.SelectedItems.Count != 0 );
    }

    public void Execute( object parameter )
    {
        //DO STUFF;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="81,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" SelectionMode="Single"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="482,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
    <Button x:Name="uButton" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Content="Upload stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="840,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="46" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" Foreground="#FF0068FF" />
```